# Custom library in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In one of my previous work I had used a custom library named "OOP"
It was working fine then.
But after a year may be. when I run it again there is these lines are not working---

```
<pre>
$data['board'] = OOP::selectOptionList(OOP::getBoard());
$data['guardiansRelation'] = OOP::selectOptionList(OOP::guardiansRelation());
</pre>
```

I think My *OOP* Library aren't working somehow. is thery any problem with my php version?
I am using `<pre>PHP version: 5.6.15<br>Apache: 2.4.17</pre>`

Comment: Check CodeIgniter Version. CodeIgniter 3 and 2 use different file naming conventions.

Comment: @BikramPahi 
This was developed on 3.0.2.
I haven't made any change on it. Just trying to run it after a year.

Comment: Could you please post the error message here.